# What does this Upgrade error means?

Tags: apt, 20.10, sssd

I get this error below when i just run sudo apt-get updata and sudo apt-get upgrade:

```
Setting up sssd-common (2.3.1-3ubuntu4) ...
Warning: found usr.sbin.sssd in /etc/apparmor.d/force-complain, forcing complain mode
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.sssd (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.sssd line 59): Caching disabled for: 'usr.sbin.sssd' due to force complain
sssd-autofs.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
sssd-nss.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
sssd-pam.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
sssd-ssh.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
sssd-sudo.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
A dependency job for sssd-autofs.socket failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
A dependency job for sssd-nss.socket failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
A dependency job for sssd-pam-priv.socket failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
A dependency job for sssd-pam.socket failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
A dependency job for sssd-ssh.socket failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
A dependency job for sssd-sudo.socket failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
```

My question is this error dangerous or is my computer too old and what does this error means i just wondering what i cannot do or what this means?

Comment: which Ubuntu version?

Comment: It is Ubuntu 20.10!

Comment: Not a question!

Comment: I don't see an error(??) I see warnings and notifications ;-) "Warning: found usr.sbin.sssd in /etc/apparmor.d/force-complain, forcing complain mode" means that the service is disabled due to an apparmor resctriction. That can be a valid situation :)

Comment: So it is not dangerous Rinzwind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like bug #1899218 - Incorrect warning from apparmor_parser on force complained profiles, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apparmor/+bug/1899218

Comment: No, it doesn't. This is the _correct_ warning, after bug #1899218 was fixed.